# python sqlite3 executemany using multiple lists

Tags: python, sql, numpy, sqlite, executemany

**Background:**
So I have a large array that I am reading from one source and trying to write (efficiently) into SQLite3 using python.

Currently I use the default form:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT into mytable1 VALUES(?,?,?)", my_arr.tolist())
```

Now I want to expand to a few hundred thousand tables. I would like to be able to do something like the following (wish):

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT into ? VALUES(?,?,?)", TableNameList, my_arr.tolist())
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to do this without inserting columns into the array
  before converting it to list?  What?
- If there is not such a way, then suggestions and alternatives are
  requested.

I tried looking in stackexchange, but may have missed something.
I tried looking in the Python SQLite docs, but did not see something like this.
I tried generic google search.

Comment: What is the type of `my_arr`?

Comment: I'm using np.empty( (row_size,col_size), dtype=object)

Comment: _"Now I want to expand to a few hundred thousand tables"_ Why? That isn't normalized. Add a column instead; where you would insert into `mytable1`, insert a `1` into the new column.

Comment: The current column is large and takes up most of the space.  If I split the table into unique tables on that column, then I get the a few hundred thousand tables (relatively small in rows) that are grouped by a value useful for summary view computation, and we get a motivating chunk of improved footprint.

Comment: Are you inserting the same `my_arr` values (multiple rows) into each of the tables, or each row of `my_arr` into a different table?  In other words, what's the mapping between the TableNameList and my_arr?

Comment: I have a high-volume AMQP provider sending inputs.  (It is not my producer, but I have a consumer) and so I build up a large table, then batch-insert it into SQLite, re-initialize the matrix, and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the Python bit. Assuming that `my_arr` is some sort of two-dimensional array, and that `.tolist()` produces a list-of-lists, Yes, there is a way to add an element to every row in your list:

```
result = [[a]+b for a,b in zip(TableNameList, my_arr.tolist()]
```

Second, the SQL bit. No, you can't use `?` to specify a table name. The table name must be literally present in the SQL statement. The best that I can offer you is to run `curssor.execute` several times:

```
for table, values in zip(TableNameList, my_arr):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?, ?, ?)"%table, values)
```

But, be mindful of whether you trust the source of `TableNameList`. Using untrusted data in a `%s` leads to SQL injection security flaws.

Sample program:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import itertools

my_arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
TableNameList = 't1', 't1', 't2', 't3'

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE t1 (c1, c2, c3)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE t2 (c1, c2, c3)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE t3 (c1, c2, c3)''')

## Insert a row of data
#c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

for table, values in itertools.izip(TableNameList, my_arr):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?, ?, ?)"%table, values)

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
conn.close()
```

Comment: The big speedup from ~100 Rows/second to ~4000 rows/second comes from the executemany well tuned.  Losing that would be a problem.

Comment: You could try one `executemany` per table. Assuming that `TableNameList` looks like `['table1', 'table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table1']` (i.e. one entry per row of `my_arr`), and that there are duplicate values in `TableNameList`, then grouping the data per table and running a single `executemany()` per table might help.